# Angular MatToolTip Condition inside Interpolation

Tags: angular

I am adding an angular condition for my MatToolTip. At first this following works for just 1 string assignment

```
matToolTip={{myData.name}}
```

But I need to add a condition like the following

```
matToolTip={{ myData.hasName : myData.name, myData.hasNoName : myData.NoNameMessage }}
```

The data coming in has one or the other, never both.

I found another stackoverflow which ppl says the following works but not in my Angular 7 code

```
{{element.source == 1 ? 'upwork' : (element.source == 2 ? 'refer from friend' : '')}}
```

I tried putting them in single quote but no success. any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

`[matTooltip]="myData.hasName ? myData.name : (myData.hasNoName? 'myData.NoNameMessage' : null)"`

Comment: doesn't work if mat-button is disabled, damn. is it because they both have [disabled] input...

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [matTooltipDisabled] directive instead of using a ternary operator or other more complex solution.

An example:

```
<mat-icon matTooltip="It's closed."
  [matTooltipDisabled]="entity.isOpen == true">
    close
</mat-icon>
```

Comment: Best answer IMO. See official documentation on `matTooltipDisabled` property [here](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use interpolation to call a typescript function on component class that will perform complex if-else scenarios. Something like this..

```
<button mat-raised-button
    matTooltip={{getToolTip(source)}}
    >
```

Action

```
getToolTip(source)  
{
var tooltip = '';
if(source==1)
{
  tooltip = 'upwork';
}
else
{
  if(source==2){
    tooltip = 'refer from friend';
  }
}
return tooltip;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The angular was just 1 line of code versus typescript which was a few more lines. The data was already there, I was getting the syntax correct. I want to keep the code lean as possible.

Comment: thats why I mentioned "complex if-else scnarios" :-)

Comment: You should avoid function in template and use a pipe. https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496